# How to check if a string contains a letter different then a given range in Java

Tags: java

I'm learning Java and I need to write a program that converts Roman numerals and traditional integers.

The code only accepts the letters MDCLXVI as Roman numerals. It does not accept any number.

This is my code:

```
System.out.print("Enter a roman numeral");
            Scanner keyb = new Scanner(System.in);
            String roman = keyb.next();

            if(roman.matches(".*[0-9].*") || **something different then M, D, C, L, X, V or I**)
        {
            System.out.println("Wrong! Re-type.");
        }
```

The problem that I'm trying to solve is how to write the second condition of the `If`.

Comment: try regex and pattern matching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first off all you have to check if the given Roman number is valid or not. So the method could look like the following:

```
public static boolean isValid(String romanNumber) {
    String pattern = "[m|d|c|l|x|v|i]*";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(romanNumber);

    return m.matches();
}
```

Then you can use this one inside your converter method. After you made this, it is necessary to convert each character inside your Roman string. So you can go ahead by creating a switch-function, which can be used inside of a for-loop.

```
public static int convertCharacter(String romanNumber, int position) {
    char c = romanNumber.charAt(position);
    switch (c) {
        case 'm':
            return 1000;
        case 'd':
            return 500;
        case 'c':
            return 100;
        case 'l':
            return 50;
        case 'x':
            return 10;
        case 'v':
            return 5;
        case 'i':
            return 1;
        default:
            return 0;
    }
}
```

And due to fact that you are new to Java, I will show you, how the converter method could be written. This one is not the best solution, but it worked for me. Using this one, it will also be possible to convert numbers like "MCMXCIX".

I deleted the comments. So try to understand what the code does. Otherwise you won't learn from it.

```
public static int convertRomanNumber(String romanNumber) {
    romanNumber = romanNumber.toLowerCase();

    if (!isValid(romanNumber)) {
        System.out.println("Invalid character detected");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    int result = 0;
    int currentNumber;
    int nextNumber;

    for (int i = 0; i < romanNumber.length(); i++) {
        currentNumber = convertCharacter(romanNumber, i);
        if (i < romanNumber.length() - 1) {
            nextNumber = convertCharacter(romanNumber, i + 1);
            if (nextNumber > currentNumber) {
                result += currentNumber * -1;
            } else {
                result += currentNumber;
            }
        } else {
            result += currentNumber;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Your input: " + romanNumber.toUpperCase());

    return result;
}
```

I hope it helps you for the future.

All the best.

Answer (score 0):

First I use `toLowerCase()` to lower case the user input, then use `matches()` to check whether the user input is equal to the character of `M D C L X V I`.

```
String user_input = "M";

if (user_input.toLowerCase().matches("m|d|c|l|x|v|i")){
    System.out.println("Matches");  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
    if(roman.matches(".*[0-9].*") || 
            !roman.matches("[MDCLXVI]"))
```

this for case insensitive:

```
    if(roman.matches(".*[0-9].*") ||
            !roman.matches("(?i)[MDCLXVI]"))
```

Comment: Thank you but your code didn't work. I got it with this one   `if(romain.matches(".*[0-9].*") || !romain.matches("[M|D|C|L|X|V|I]*"))`

Comment: Can you tell me what string did you try and what was the outcome?